# Is it safe to replace android-support-v4.jar shipped with libraries with the latest

Tags: android

From time to time, Google will release latest version of android-support-v4.jar

Most of the time, there are quite a number of 3rd party libraries depend on this jar file. ***They shipped with their own version of android-support-v4.jar.***

- [ActionBarSherlock](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock)
- [Android-ViewPagerIndicator](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator)
- [SlidingMenu](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu)
- [PinnedHeaderListView](https://github.com/JimiSmith/PinnedHeaderListView)

I was wondering, is it safe for me, by just merely replace their shipped old android-support-v4.jar, with the latest android-support-v4.jar released by Google?

I tested. It seems to work with some basic test. I'm not sure is there any catches behind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best answer is probably, but there's no way to be sure.  If Google didn't accidentally add a bug, then it will probably work.  If they did, things may break.  Or if the library depended on an old bug that Google fixed.  Chances are you'll be safe, but you can never be sure without testing.